# LLC SMPS Problem

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, synchronous

[image: V9-10-111][image: VDS-VGS on Problematic MOSFETs][image: Sync. rectifier (OUTPUT)]
[image: Whole Circuit]I faced with a problem in a LLC SMPS which I designed,
The mentioned PS is a 200 W/6.3 VDC, Input is 85-240 VAC (including PFC),
For the output rectifying, I used 4 MOSFETs (IRL8113) as active rectifier which drive and controlled with MP6924 as a synchronous rectification controller.

Now the main problem which has confused me is: both MOSFETs in one side get hot abnormally while the both MOSFETs on the opposite side work in normal temperature,
The voltage between drain & source of all MOSFETs are the same (15 V),
The PCB layout is corrected, tracks between transformer and MOSFETs are as short as possible with the same length and size, [please see attached picture].

Meanwhile when I exchange the output pins of the transformer to the MOSFETs, the problem's location is the same, But when I swap the "input" pins of the transformer, the problem's location changes as well, I means the MOSFETs on the opposite side which have worked in normal temperature, get hot abnormally after swapping of the transformer's input pins!

It would be highly appreciated if you recommend me a solution,
[Whole Circuit Picture also is attached]
Many thanks with best regards,
Ehsan

Comment: Welcome! Please show oscillograms, especially Vgs and Vds for the problematic MOSFETs.

Comment: Why is the sync rect controller grounded to the wrong side of the output CMC? Why an output CMC in the first place?

Comment: Not what you asked about, but your 14NK50Z 500 V MOSFETs on the primary side with 400 V DC rail is too little margin for comfort.

Comment: "Why an output CMC in the first place?"
What do you mean Tim? would you please give me more explanation?

Comment: It may very well be a lack of symmetry of the secondary-side leakage inductance between the two secondary windings. The best would be to capture the currents flowing out of each secondary and plot them on a common graph for comparison. If the asymmetry is too large, then conduction losses are naturally increased on one leg and it seems confirmed by swapping the output pins. You could also characterize the transformer to highlight this potential difference in the leakage terms.

Comment: Dear Winny, The oscillogram of Vds & Vgs is attached

Comment: Same remark as *Tim Williams*, the \$V_{GS}\$ waveforms are ugly (you should have square waveforms) and indicate a possibly bad grounding for the driver. Its ground should go straight to the sources of the sync rect MOSFETs, not after the chokes.

Comment: Insufficient Vgs to turn it on. How does Vdd and LL look on the IC? What does your layout look like?

Comment: Dear friends, Many thanks for your nice recommendation,
please note that , I should correct and also remark some points:
1- when I swap the "input" pins of the transformer, the problem's location changes as well, I means the MOSFETs on the opposite side which have work in normal temperature, get hot abnormally after the exchange of transformer's input pins!
2-I Bypassed the "EMI Inductor" so the driver is grounded to Mosfets Directly,
3- I replaced 4 Mosfets with 4 Schottky diodes, ( no gate driving, No losses), but the same problem is existing! one side get hot!

Comment: How does transformer pin 9 and 11 voltage look like with respect to pin 10?

Comment: Vp-p of pin 9 & 11 are 15V respect to pin 10

Comment: Please show with an oscillogram.

Comment: Please see the oscillogram, the voltage on the Pin 11 respect to pin 10 belong to the leg which get hot,

Comment: L6599A datasheet specifies 48-52% duty cycle. Clearly you are not getting this out. Investigate why this is occurring. Examples could include supply or output ripple, or EMI/RFI, into the RF or CF pins and related components.

Comment: Looks like you have one more turn on the winding with higher voltage or unbalance on primary side midpoint.

Comment: In the application example in the datasheet there is a crude additional circuit with two resistors, a diode and a capacitor at the CF pin. This looks like an attempt to adjust the symmetry of the triangle waveform and implicit the generated duty cycle. This may be a kind of bugfix.